# How to check if two objects (UIButtons ) are the same

Tags: ios, uitableview, tags, uibutton

First off tags wont work. I say this because i create 4 buttons all with the same tag for a specific cell i.e indexPath.row = tag.

Inside My TableViewCellForRowAtIndexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"courseCell";

//Step 1: Check to se if we can reuse a cell from a row that has just rolled off the screen
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//step 2: If there are no cell to reuse, create a new one
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
}
...


    //-------------Creation of Custom Buttons-------------// 

    //-----img = "radioOn.png"-----//
    //----img2 = "radioOff.png"----//

    //----RadioButtonA----//
    ...

    radioButtonA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [radioButtonA addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    radioButtonA.tag=indexPath.row;

    //----End RadioButtonA----//

    //----RadioButtonB----//

    radioButtonB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [radioButtonB addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   radioButtonB.tag =indexPath.row;
...

    //----End RadioButtonB----//

    //----RadioButtonC----//

    radioButtonC = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [radioButtonC addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    radioButtonC.tag = indexPath.row;
...

    //----End RadioButtonC----//

    //----RadioButtonNA----//

    radioButtonNA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    radioButtonNA.tag = indexPath.row;
    [radioButtonNA addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    ...

    //----End RadioButtonC----//

    //---------End of Radio Button Creations---------//

    //---------UIStepper & StepperLabel Creation-----//




    [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonA];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonB];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonC];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonNA];

//Step4: Return the cell
return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Buttons

- (void)radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
 {

UIButton *myButton = sender;


// This Method and all the ones similar to this method is created to handle the UITouchUpInsideEvent that the user sends when pressing the radioButtons A-NA.

[radioButtons addObject:sender];

// Create an instance(object) of class NSIndexPath called indexPath and set its value the indexPath of the cell the user is currently in.
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];


// Initialize two unique variables in order to check if the buttons being clicked are being referenced in the correct index. 
int row = indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"Button is in row %d", row);

...

}

-(IBAction)button:(UIButton*)sender{
  ...
@try {
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {

        if ([credits count ] ==0) {
            break; 
        }
```

HERE is where i am trying to access the radiobuttons i created in my cell. What i would like to do is this

if([credits objectAtIndex:i]) == radioButtonA{

do stuff. The reason im not saying  == [radioButtonA tag] is because i have three other buttons all with the same tag. If your read the code u see why the tags are set this way.
}

What I am asking for is 1 help, and 2 is there another way to check if two Buttons i.e objects are equal without having to rely on their tags.

Do not worry about the Try catch finally i was using it to catch the exception being thrown.

```
        if ([[[[credits objectAtIndex:i]titleLabel]text] isEqualToString:@"A"])  {
            NSLog(@"radioA is in array");
            creditHours+=[[valueArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
            gradeEarned+=(GradeA.doubleValue *[[valueArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
            NSLog(@"%f",gradeEarned);
            continue;
        }

        if ([[[[credits objectAtIndex:i]titleLabel]text] isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
            NSLog(@"radioB is in array");
            creditHours+=[[valueArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
            gradeEarned+=(GradeB.doubleValue *[[valueArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
            continue;
        }

        if ([[[[credits objectAtIndex:i]titleLabel]text] isEqualToString:@"C"]){
            NSLog(@"radioC is in array");
            creditHours+=[[valueArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
            gradeEarned+=(GradeC.doubleValue *[[valueArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
            continue;
        }

        if([credits objectAtIndex:i]== radioButtonNA){
            NSLog(@"boboboobbobob");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"NSException Caught");
    NSLog(@"Name: %@",exception.name);
    NSLog(@"Reason: %@", exception.reason);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"in finally block");
}

//        if ([credits objectAtIndex: i] == defaulter) {
//                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed to select all grades" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your grade selections have been reset"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"great"otherButtonTitles:nil];
//                        [alert show];
//                        [alert release];
//            [self refreshArray];
//        }


NSLog(@"%f",gradeEarned);

if (gradeEarned == 0) {
    textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",gradeEarned];
}else {
    NSLog( @"boob");
    sum= (gradeEarned)/(creditHours);
    NSLog(@"%f",sum);
    textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",sum];
    //[self refreshArray];
}

}
```

For more information Here is the log...
 NSLog(@"%@",[credits objectAtIndex:i]);
 NSLog(@"%@",radioButtonA);

```
      THE First output is the log of the [credits object atIndex:i]
```

UIButton: 0x6c91430; frame = (86 110; 32 30); opaque = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x6c914f0

2012-06-20 20:24:01.568 TableView[12557:f803] UIButton: 0x6ea8ad0; frame = (86 110; 32 30); opaque = NO; tag = 6; layer = CALayer: 0x6e746e0

As you can see The UIBUttons are DIFFERENT thus == operator does not work

Comment: == should work fine. Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? stack trace?

Comment: Agreed with the above comment, specifically, `==` applied to objects tests the address for equality so, if it's the same object referenced by a different variable, it will be at that one address.

Comment: here is the log...    NSLog(@"%@",[credits objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSLog(@"%@",radioButtonA);                 THE First output is the log of the [credits object atIndex:i]      2012-06-20 20:22:14.219 TableView[12536:f803] <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x6848a70; frame = (160 419; 160 41); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6848b60>>                                                            This second log is the log of radioButtonA
2012-06-20 20:22:14.220 TableView[12536:f803] <UIButton: 0x6e94350; frame = (86 110; 32 30); opaque = NO; tag = 6; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e94290>>

Comment: So in every row you have 4 buttons right...how many rows do you have for example (with those 4 btns)?

Comment: i have 8 rows in each row  there are 4 buttons as well as labels etc

Comment: Why do you have all four buttons have the same tag if you then in radioButtonClicked get the NSIndexPath, from which you can get section and row + if you had 4 different tags you would have all info you need...

Comment: @Ladislav I set all button tags the same for this line of code...     
    for(int i=0;i<[radioButtons count];i++){

        if ([[radioButtons objectAtIndex:i]tag]==[sender tag]) {
            [[radioButtons objectAtIndex:i] setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
            [sender setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

Comment: so if you know which row was clicked and which button was clicked you know everything you need to know...what's the problem then?

Comment: How do objects get placed into the `credits` array?  Also, as you point out, those two `UIButton` objects are different.  What makes you think that they should be the same?

Comment: @PhillipMills  I created a custom method that takes the sender which is a UIButton from the radioButtonClicked method and store that button at an index that corresponds to the indexpath.row that the SENDER was in.

Comment: @Ladislav Yes since the tags are the same on all the buttons i know what row the button was in but i do now know which button was pressed. I must know which button was pressed in order to do a specific task. Each button at the end of a program is compared inorder to see if the task for that button should be performed

Comment: That is what I am saying have 4 buttons with 4 different tags...

Comment: @Ladislav OK the only reason i do not use this approach is because my buttons must be grouped so when i click one the image changes and when i click another it goes back to the original image

Comment: @Ladislav  that is what this is for     for(int i=0;i<[radioButtons count];i++){
        if ([[radioButtons objectAtIndex:i]tag]==[sender tag]) {
            [[radioButtons objectAtIndex:i] setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
            [sender setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: sorry but do not get it...sorry

Comment: no thank you, although no solution was found you still helped me. i think im going to try and use the 4 different tag approach again and rework my for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, in the method, 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`
 you should add the buttons only when the cell is nil.just like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"courseCell";

    //Step 1: Check to se if we can reuse a cell from a row that has just rolled off the screen
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //step 2: If there are no cell to reuse, create a new one
    if (cell == nil)
    {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
         //-------------Creation of Custom Buttons-------------// 

         //-----img = "radioOn.png"-----//
         //----img2 = "radioOff.png"----//

         //----RadioButtonA----//
          ...

         radioButtonA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

         [radioButtonA addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         radioButtonA.tag=indexPath.row;

         //----End RadioButtonA----//

         //----RadioButtonB----//

         radioButtonB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         [radioButtonB addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         radioButtonB.tag =indexPath.row;
         ...

//----End RadioButtonB----//

//----RadioButtonC----//

         radioButtonC = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         [radioButtonC addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         radioButtonC.tag = indexPath.row;
         ...

//----End RadioButtonC----//

//----RadioButtonNA----//

           radioButtonNA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           radioButtonNA.tag = indexPath.row;
         [radioButtonNA addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

...

//----End RadioButtonC----//

//---------End of Radio Button Creations---------//

//---------UIStepper & StepperLabel Creation-----//




       [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonA];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonB];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonC];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButtonNA];
 }
     ...

    //Step4: Return the cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How about using a custom cell?

Answer (score 5):

When checking two object against one another you cannot use ==, you have to use `[objectA isEqual:objectB]`, if those two objects are the same the answer will be YES and NO if they are not.

To read more go to: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

and check what is written for isEqual:

Comment: the objects [objectA isEqual:objectB] will never be equal in my program... when  a button is clicked  the sender is being placed into an array and that sender (UIButton) is being changed everytime the program runs. I would not have posted this question if that was the solution i have tried all the solutions i could think of, so i posted on here to recieve help. Thank you, even though your method will not work.

Comment: Correct! Also, if you are comparing objects of the same type, you can use these more specialized functions: 'isEqualToString:`, `isEqualToArray`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had already known this, however, the purpose of this post was to see if their are any other ways. I also used the  isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class] to further narrow down. Best way and most effective way of doing this is using the object's tags to compare against.